# Access VBA DlookUp Query SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

> Syntax Error:

```
availableUnits = Nz((DLookup("[AvailableUnits]", "Stock", "Symbol = '" & Me.CBSymbol.Column(1) & "'"),"")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your questions are getting down-voted because they doesn't include enough detail for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. [SO - How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Everyone is down voting this question so I'm going to write a brief explanation. This new user is likely using a version of `MS-Access` to write their `VBA` code. On older versions of `Access`, if there is an error in the `VBA` code the debugger only takes you to that line and states either 'Error' or 'Syntax Error'; nothing else.  We should encourage good question asking to maintain the integrity of this site, but keep in mind that this is quite literally all the information this user had to go on before asking us here. This error is also not easily fixed if you don't know what syntax means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis on this line after `Nz`

```
availableUnits = Nz(DLookup("[AvailableUnits]", "Stock", "Symbol ='" & Me.CBSymbol.Column(1) & "'"),"")
```

Use `Notepadd++` to make checking this kind of stuff much easier.